# APIs created via super tenant publisher are not available in developer portal/ publisher of other tenants

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, apim

I am using wso2 API manager 3.1.0 and wso2 IS as KM 5.10.0 . I created the tenants in API manager's carbon console. When I created some APIs via super tenant's publisher portal and set the subscription availability to specific tenants as shown in below figure. Also the developer portal visibility is set to public.

[image]

But when I login to the developer portals of one of the tenant to which I configured the subscription to be availble in previous step I am unable to see the API. Is this a Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checked for the API in the **specific tenant's Developer Portal**, the API will **not** be visible. Since the API is created by the super tenant which is carbon.super, the API is only accessible from the **carbon.super developer portal space**. If you login as a different tenant to the carbon.super developer portal space, then you will be able to see the API.

The API will be **visible and subscribable** for the tenants that you have specified under "Subscription Availability" section in Publisher given their visibility is Public according to your scenario. For this you have to login to carbon.super Developer Portal Space.

See the image below where you can select the tenant developer portal you need to log into. Try logging into carbon.super space with the specific tenant credentials.

[image]